# Automate Unit Testing in Jenkins

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a pl/sql project in SQL Developer. I use SQL Developer unit test for performing unit tests on the PL/SQL project.

I am trying to implement continuous integration for this project by using Jenkins.

I want to know how can I configure Jenkins to run these unit tests of SQL Developer ?

Any information or suggestions would be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: There is a command line utility to run the unit tests https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15846_01/doc.21/e15222/unit_testing.htm#RPTUG45000 you may write a shell/batch to invoke this and integrate the shell in the jenkins